# MS Project: Finish Variance formula simplification

Tags: ms-project, scheduling, ms-project-2013

I've set a formula to monitor variance between baseline and scheduled finish. I know that there is a simple finish variance column for this kind of thing, but in my organization we've got certain deviations thresholds so default field set will not work.
Please take a look at this

`Switch(Not [Baseline Finish]=[Scheduled Finish];Iif((DateDiff("d";[Baseline Finish];[Scheduled Finish])>14) OR (DateDiff("d";[Baseline Finish];[Scheduled Finish])<-14);DateDiff("d";[Baseline Finish];[Scheduled Finish]);"");([Baseline Finish]=[Scheduled Finish] And [% Complete]=100) Or ([Baseline Finish]=[Scheduled Finish] And [% Complete]=0);"")`

What is achieved here is that in a text30 field the variance data is only displayed if it meets certain threshold parameters (e.g. -14 and +14 days).
The need for this is that i do have a set of flags that trigger to YES/NO depending on text30 column data (e.g. red arrow if deviation is >60 or green arrow if deviation is >15<31 etc). And then based on those flags the custom milestone icons are displayed on gantt.
Question is how can i simplify the a/m formula?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
Switch([Finish Variance]/[Minutes Per Day]<=-14,[Finish Variance]/[Minutes Per Day],[Finish Variance]/[Minutes Per Day]>=14,[Finish Variance]/[Minutes Per Day],[Finish Variance]/[Minutes Per Day]<14 And [Finish Variance]/[Minutes Per Day]>-14," ")

As you are testing for % complete in the flag formulas I'd just show [Finish Variance] in Text30.  Because you are using a text field, the Finish Variance is going to be in minutes - hence dividing it by [Minutes per day]

Comment: Oh i forgot to mention that % Complete check is there to have a text30 field empty when task is marked as %complete=100 even though if there is a schedule variance in place. Basically if the task is complete then forget about the variance and don't show it to anyone. However it is not really working as intended... So probably there is a logical error there somewhere...

Comment: Then add one more test, result  of ([% complete] = 100, " ") as the first in the series.  The formula stops at the first true result.

Comment: I tried your formula but the result differs. e.g. my formula shows 26days variance between 19.08.16 baseline and 14.09.16 scheduled finish. When i apply yours, it shows 18days instead. It seems to skip holidays. For our internal reporting reasons we reflect delays with holidays included

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Are you saying that you count non-working days (Saturday and Sunday) when calculating variance?  Were the resource scheduled to work during Saturday and Sunday?

Comment: In our case we do not use resource planning at all. It is all based on calendar planning. This is just how it is in mt organization

Comment: Okay - but when you say a task takes 7 days - does that include Saturday and Sunday?  The Finish Variance calculation is based upon the project calendar definition.  So, if you want to count calendar days for both duration and duration variance - then use a calendar where every day is a working day.  Otherwise you are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Ok i understand. Thank you very much for your time and input!